# ag-grid sort by column A using hidden column B

Tags: ag-grid

Is there a way to sort by column A (user clicks on A column header) but under the hood use column B?

For example, I have a column "name" that displays a user's name. But then I have a column "name frequency in general population" that is hidden. I want to display the regular "name" but sort by the other column under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own customer comparator and set it to your `name` field by using [Custom Sorting](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/row-sorting/#custom-sorting).

With custom sorting, you have access to all the data in each row where you can choose what should go where.

```
var columnDefs = [
  { field: 'name', comparator: customComparator },
  { field: 'name frequency in general population' },
];

function customComparator(valueA, valueB, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) {
  const nodeAValue = nodeA.data['name frequency in general population'];
  const nodeBValue = nodeB.data['name frequency in general population'];
  return (nodeAValue > nodeBValue) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Note if you're sorting on a pivot grid, you'll need to use `defaultGroupSortComparator` setting on the gridOptions